# Save image to MySQL as MediumBlob?

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

previously im able to save it successfully if the field in MySQL is a BLOB. However, if I change the table structure to MEDIUMBLOB/LONGBLOB, the data is not inserted into the database. I'm not sure why.

Here is the code for me to insert to the database as a BLOB.

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['selectedfile']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['selectedfile']['name']);
    $checkedcondition = implode(",",$_POST['skincondition']);
    $checkedproduct = implode(",",$_POST['skincareinuse']);
    $consultquery="INSERT INTO counsel(nric,dateconsulted,timeconsulted,customerface,imagename,skincarecurrentlyinuse,skincondition,skincareremarks,skinconditionremarks) VALUES('$_SESSION[nric]','$_POST[storedate]','$_POST[storetime]','{$image}','{$image_name}','$checkedproduct','$checkedcondition','$_POST[productremarks]','$_POST[conditionremarks]')";
    mysqli_query($dbconn,$consultquery);
```

However, if i change to a MEDIUMBLOB table structure, and when i print the selectedfile array, it doesn't show any error however the data is still not inserted into the database.
[image]

Comment: just to give some advice saving blob and large text king of data in mysql will not be a good practice.

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka ahh i've seen people saying this everywhere. So its better to saving it to a separate folder? But how do i know that photo belongs to a certain person from a database if i save it to the folder?

Comment: simple: you write the URL of the image in your database..

Comment: please don't do this

Comment: As a DBA, I am diametrically opposed to storing these blobs.  Unless all blobs are the same size.  If you do "have" to store them, create a sidecar table to put them in that is out of line of most of your queries.  And, under NO circumstances allow developers to do a "select *" from the table.  This is a very bad practice.